# How to convert Timer.Enabled to type Control

Tags: vb.net, vb6

After converting code from VB6 to VB.NET I got the following resultant code:

**Designer Form Code:**

```
Public WithEvents Timer1 As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.TimerArray
Me.Timer1 = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.TimerArray(components)
```

**Code Implementation:**

```
Private Function GetBaseControl(ByRef a_type As String) As System.Windows.Forms.Control Implements GetBaseControl

Select Case a_type

Case "Web"
        GetBaseControl = ctBrowser1(0)
Case "Timer"
        GetBaseControl = Timer1(0)

End Select
End Function
```

Here the Error I've received:

> Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' at Line `GetBaseControl = Timer1(0)`.

That works fine in VB6 Though !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this ever worked in VB6, the code was following some very poor practices to return the Boolean `Enabled` instead of the actual `Timer` component. It implies, at minimum, that Option Strict was off, and that's really bad.

In this case, `Timers` in .Net are no longer considered Controls at all. Instead, they are `Components`. You'll want to re-think how this code functions. An example of how the code is used might let us recommend a different (better) approach to the problem.

In this case, I suspect re-thinking this to use overloaded methods (which was not idiomatic for vb6) will produce better results, especially with regards to preserving type safety rather than passing strings around.

---

Note: this answer made more sense before the question was edited the next day

Comment: Even if I remove that still got a error: Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

Comment: Ah, that's right... Timers are **Components**, not Controls. And even if they weren't, you're still using the compatibility namespace. You'll find that .Net is particular that you know the precise **type** of each object you use, where vb6/vbscript was much less picky. In time you'll get used to this and see it as a strength, but it can get in the way as you first learn .Net.

Comment: Any preferable solution? How can I solve this error?